# rails form skips validation and doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

My rails form skips validation and doesn't save. Any ideas on why this is happening?

What ends up happening is that the form submits and it goes to the create action, but it skips the validation completely set up in contact.rb and this line in the contact controller's @contact.save doesn't save and it goes to the else.

This is what gets printed in the terminal server window after the contact form gets submitted with dummy data:

```
logged in #<Contact:0xb60b3978>


Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-11 17:04:46 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zbEGKGXz1t2Os6VjVOMzcfeHru9sBfoBaF6tgr16qPo=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "subject"=>"", "body"=>""}, "category"=>"bug", "commit"=>"Contact Us"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contact
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-11 17:04:46 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
  Rendered common/_form_errors.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered contacts/_contact_form.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered common/_search_form.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flashmessages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 72ms (Views: 71.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user    

    attr_accessible :body, :category, :email, :name, :subject

    validates :body, presence: true, length: { in: 10..255 }

    validates :category, presence: true

    validates :name, presence: true

    validates :email, presence: true

    validates :subject, presence: true


end
```

_contact_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @contact %>
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="well">
                <%= f.label :name, "What's your name?" %> 

                <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "field span4" %>
            </div>

            <div class="well">

                <%= f.label :email, "Your Email so we can hit you back." %> 
                <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "field span4" %>
            </div>

            <div class="well">
                <%= f.label :category, "Pick one:" %> 
                <%= select_tag(:category, 
                options_for_select(
                [['I found a bug.', 'bug'], ['I have a suggestion.', 'suggestion'], ['other', 'other']]
                )) %>
            </div>

            <div class="well">
                <%= f.submit "Contact Us", :class=> "marginTopBottom" %> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
            <div class="well">
                <%= f.label :subject, "Subject:" %> 

                <%= f.text_field :subject, :class => "field span4" %>
            </div>

            <div class="well">
                <%= f.label :body, "What's Up?" %> 

                <%= f.text_area(:body, :rows => 7, :class => "field span4") %>
            </div>


        </div>
<% end %>
```

contacts/new.html.erb:

```
<%= provide(:navActive, 'Contact Us') %>
<h1>Contact Us</h1>

<div class="row">
    <%= render 'contact_form' %>
</div>
```

contacts_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    if logged_in?
      @contact = current_user.contacts.build(params[:contact])
      puts "logged in #{@contact}" # prints out when logged in
    else 
      @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
      @contact.user_id = 999999
      puts "not logged in #{@contact}" # prints out when not logged in
    end

    if @contact.save
        flash[:success] = "Your message was sent and we'll get back to you as soon as possible!"

        # send an email to offering poster about the new request
        UserMailer.contact(@contact, sent_at = Time.now).deliver
        redirect_to contact_path
    else
      flash[:success] = "Your message was not sent. Something went wrong. Please contact pavankat@gmail.com."
      redirect_to contact_path
    end

  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "contacts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "contacts", ["user_id"], :name => "index_contacts_on_user_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= f.select(:category, 
                options_for_select(
                [['I found a bug.', 'bug'], ['I have a suggestion.', 'suggestion'], ['other', 'other']]
                )) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's skipping the validation, I think there's no way for your page to show the error.

You need to add `<%= flash[:success] %>` somewhere on the page.

You can also output errors for the `contact` object, which might help!

(You may refute this by posting the content of `common/form_errors` -

Comment: Oh it's actually printing the flash message in the else of the create method of the contacts controller: "Your message was not sent. Something went wrong. Please contact pavankat@gmail.com." I'll try output the errors thanks!